# Have to submit ajax form twice to submit it

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a simple AJAX form but i have to click the submit button twice to submit tried lot of solutions from stackoverflow nothing seems to work can some one please help

Update:

changed

```
<button type="submit" class=" btn btn-info btn-large-maxi">LANCEZ L'ANALYSE GRATUITE</button>
```

to

```
<button  class=" btn btn-info btn-large-maxi">LANCEZ L'ANALYSE GRATUITE</button>
```

and it now works Thanks for the unknown commenter who provided the solution

```
$('#etude-accueil').submit(function(e) {  

    $('#loader').html('<h1 style="margin:auto;text-align: center;">Generating Theme</h1><br><img src="load.gif"   alt="">');
    $(".benifit-result").addClass("ajax-load");

    $.post('/free/forcast/votre-resultats.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {


        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.benifit-result').html(data);
            $('#nav-buy').html("<a id='promo-button' href='pay.php'  class='btn btn-info btn-large-maxi pull-right'   >Buy Template</a>");
            $('#navigation').html("<a href='pay.php' id='mobile-nav'  class='btn btn-info btn-large-maxi '   >Buy Template</a>");

        }, 7000);
    });


    e.preventDefault();

});

jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() {

        $('#loader').show();


    },
    complete: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#loader').hide();
        }, 7000);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".benifit-result").removeClass("ajax-load");
        }, 7000);
    }
});
```

Comment: with 7 second delay are you sure it's not posting the first time?

Comment: ya some times it posts in first try but many times its not posting

Comment: Why are you processing response after 7 second of callback??

Comment: to show the loading icon :) btw i think the problem is solved
a user commented her to try using a normal button than a button with a type as submit tried it and it works i don't know why he deleted his answer :(